# How to setup data for R package:vegan

Tags: r, dataset, vegan

I'm planning on analyzing alpha diversity metrics(species richness, Shannon, abundance curves, etc) using count data from a dataset. Since the data was over multiple years and multiple sites I totaled each sites counts per year for each individual species in Excel. Essentially making a matrix with the species codes for each column and years for each row(i'm only interested in differences between years not sites). So its setup like this essentially.

```
Year Spec1  Spec2  Spec3 ...etc.
2022. 2       4     
2021. 5       6
2020. 10      20
...etc
```

I'm running into some difficulty with data setup so R can read it properly. Does anyone have insight on using vegan and if the data is ok to import like this? I have not analyzed biodiversity metrics before in R with vegan so I could use some insight.

Comment: I believe it’s more of a stats question in regards to R(I’m not too familiar with overflow though; I’ve only ever used exchange). I’m using vegan to determine biodiversity metrics from animal count data. The objective is to see if there are differences between years of the counts(i.e if species numbers have been decreasing or increasing depending on the year for example). I setup the data as shown above but get errors for most formula outputs. I’m mostly curious if anyone has used vegan in a similar ecology question and has tips for setting up data for R. I’ve not used vegan before.

Comment: Can you post the error, and what you posted above, in the question body?